# Move zeros to the end of list

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm working on the problem of moving all the zeros in the array to the end.
I know this has been asked before but I'm not looking for the solution - my problem is that I can't think in a logical way to stop the loop because I implemented it on Python and it loops forever.
This is what I have:

```
def move_zeros(array):
    i=0
    
    while i<len(array):
        if array[i] == 0:
            for j in range(i, len(array)-1):
                array[j] = array[j+1]
            array[len(array)-1] = 0
        else:
            i+=1
            
    return array
```

The only thing I can think right now is to add a counter outside the if-else and use break when the counter is equal to the length of the array, like this:

```
def move_zeros(array):
    i=0
    count = 0
    while i<len(array):
        if array[i] == 0:
            for j in range(i, len(array)-1):
                array[j] = array[j+1]
            array[len(array)-1] = 0
        else:
            i+=1
            
        count += 1
        if count == len(array):
            break
    return array
```

But I know this is cheating in some way because I used python and knew it was going on forever, and I don't want to search for the problem online because I don't want to see the full solution... Any help? Thank you.

Comment: How is that cheating?

Comment: The outer loop should be `for count in range(len(array))` because  A) you know you need to check exactly `len(array)` elements, regardless of whether `i` increments or not, and B) if there *is* a 0 in the array, the `while` loop is worthless because `i` will never reach the end of the array. So throw the `while` loop away and just count the elements with the `for` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conceptually, imagine that instead of putting the zeroes to the end of the array, you just remove them, shifting everything else back. In that case, when you don't find a zero, you still increment `i` by 1, but when you do find a zero, the "array length" also gets smaller by 1. Let's define a new variable `limit` which keeps track of this imaginary length; the zeroes will still get swapped to the end of the array, but the loop ends when `i` reaches this limit (because the rest of the array is all the zeroes you "removed" on earlier iterations).

```py
def move_zeros(array):
    i = 0
    limit = len(array)
    while i < limit:
        if array[i] == 0:
            for j in range(i, limit - 1):
                array[j] = array[j + 1]
            array[limit - 1] = 0
            limit -= 1
        else:
            i += 1
    return array
```

This loop provably terminates in `len(array)` iterations, because on each iteration either `i` increases or `limit` decreases, making them closer together by 1 and eventually the loop terminates because they become equal.