# How can I move zeroes to the end of a list?

Tags: python, list

I have an array of integers like:

```
nums = [0, 1, 0, 3, 12]
```

I want to move all '0's to the end of it, while maintaining the relative order of the non-zero elements. So the desired output is `[1, 3, 12, 0, 0]`.

I made the following attempts:

```
temp = 0
for i in range(len(nums)):
    if nums[i] == 0:
        nums.pop(i)
        temp += 1
print(temp)
```

In this code, I got an error saying that `nums[i]` has an index out of range. Why? `len(nums) == 5`, so the `i` values should all be valid.

```
nums = [0,1,0,3,12]
nums.sort()
temp = 0
for i in range(len(nums)-1):
    if nums[i] == 0:
        print(nums[i])
        temp +=1
        nums.pop(i)
print(nums)
for _ in range(temp):
    nums.append(0)
print(nums)
```

With this code, the first `print` gives an output of `[0, 1, 3, 12]`, so in the final result, not all of the zeroes are moved. Why were they not all popped by the first loop?

Comment: "why nums[i] is out of index, if range" because you're deleting items from the list

Comment: I guess it doesn’t work because some of the zeroes in front of the pointer had shifted left by the time the pointer reached them. Changing the order / number of items in a list while looping it is generally a bad idea. The index may go out of range if ye don’t update the limit.

Comment: You should NOT change the `list` while looping it. That's why you got the Index error.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. There are two possible questions here. One of them is "why didn't these approaches work the way I want?" That *would* be two separate questions normally, but the problem is the same for both code samples so it is okay. However, that question is a duplicate. The other possibility is "how can I write code that solves the original problem?". There are much better approaches to the question. Which way should we answer this?

Comment: Just for fun, you could try this - `print(sorted(nums, key=lambda x: not x))`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Move zeros to the end of list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67143772/move-zeros-to-the-end-of-list)

Comment: The original example is not clear. The code in your second attempt sorts the list, but that does not help to solve the problem, and it seemed like you do not want to change the order of the non-zero elements. To make it clear about whether or how you want output to be sorted, it is a good idea to **start with data that is not sorted already**.

Comment: @DanielHao That is a perfectly reasonable way to solve the problem, and I think you should write it up as an answer, explaining in detail how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q1) When you pop out the item, the length of `nums` is decreased. For loops will not adjust the range being iterated over, so in this case `range(len(nums))` will always be `range(5)` as this was the original length. This means that `nums[4]` is called, which results in an index error because the item that used to be at this index has moved backwards in the list due to the removal of prior values.

A solution is to use a while loop, as the condition `i < len(nums)` will be checked at every iteration. You will have to manually increment i.

Q2) If the indices of values in the list decreases as items are popped, some values will be skipped.

A solution in tandem with a while loop is to only increment i if the condition `nums[i] == 0` is not met.

```
nums = [0,1,0,3,12]
nums.sort()
temp = 0
i = 0
while i < len(nums):
    if nums[i] == 0:
        print(nums[i])
        temp += 1
        nums.pop(i)
    else:
        i += 1
print(nums)
for _ in range(temp):
    nums.append(0)
print(nums)
```

There are definitely easier ways to solve the same problem, as shown in other solutions, but I hope this way is easy to understand.

Answer (score 3):

I think one way you can get the desired output is to separate the `nums` list into two list that doesn't contain zeros and one does using list comprehension and concat the two list together

```
nums = [0,1,0,3,12]
new_list = [n for n in nums if n != 0] + [n for n in nums if n == 0]
```

Edit: per @DanielHao's suggestion, you can also use [sorted key lambda](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#key-functions) with `lambda x: not x` which will then interprets zeroes as 1 and non-zeroes as 0 when sorting the list

```
nums = [0,1,0,3,12]
nums[:] = sorted(nums, key=lambda x: not x)
```

Comment: Simpler approach - `nums[:] = sorted(nums, key=lambda x: not x)` In-place, same list.

Comment: It works - because 0 -> `not 0` becomes True `1`.  And you don't need to create a new list.

Comment: @DanielHao hmm you're right. That's a really creative use of sorted keys. Updated my answer

Comment: this will be slow for larger lists as this is O(n^2) in terms of complexity

Comment: @gold_cy shouldn't the sorted complexity be O(nlogn) but I think you're right that the performance might be worse than having O(2n) list comprehension approach in larger lists

Answer (score 0):

```
nums = [0, 1, 0, 3, 12]
temp =0
new_nums=[]
for x in range(0,len(nums)):
   if(nums[x]==0):
    temp +=1
   else:
    new_nums.append(nums[x])
    
while(temp != 0):
new_nums.append(0)
temp -=1


print(new_nums)
```

This code work efficiently to produce desired output.

Answer (score -2):

1] You are popping the list element so the list length changes hence getting out of index error

2] Code:

```
nums = [0,1,0,3,12]
# Get count of 0's
count = nums.count(0)
# List without 0's
nums = [ i for i in nums if i!=0 ]
# Add 0's to the end 
[nums.append(0) for i in range(count)]
print(nums)
```

Comment: can you explain 1

Comment: Why are you doing `nums.sort()`?

Comment: @HimanshuPingulkar He wrote: “while maintaining the relative order of the non-zero elements”.

Comment: Yeah you guys are right

Comment: You should not use list comprehension to repeatedly execute functions with side effects. Instead, you should use the for loop directly.